# how to use json response in wpf application

Tags: c#, php, json, wpf

My wpf application is communicating with php web api. First I post some data to web api and recieved json resonse. At server side php script just prepared an array and `json_encode(arrayName)`is sent to client. At my client side I am using following code

```
using (WebResponse jsonResponse = request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Do something with response
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(jsonResponse.GetResponseStream());
                String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                MessageBox.Show(responseData);
            }
```

in the message box I am able to see all the data sent by server. Now I don't have any idea how to assign this data to local variables? Kindly guide me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/drptj.png

**EDIT**

Response shown in message box is :-

```
[{"response":"true","user_id":"250","username":"sapan108"}]'
```

After Googling I created following class :-

```
public class UserData
{
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Now How to assign json response to these variables.

Note: Due to less reputation unable to post image directly. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Post the json data as a text also do you have a object to assign data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should create class to represent json data (http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string current_balance { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string outh_token { get; set; }
    public List<string> lastFiveSpinNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

2) You should deserialize json data into class (the easiest way is to using Json.NET library - http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
using (WebResponse jsonResponse = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Do something with response
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(jsonResponse.GetResponseStream());
    String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseData);  
    // process your data
    foreach (var rootObject in myData)
    {
        string response = rootObject.response;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the last line(JsonConvert) I am getting error. Which reference have I to add in my code to use JsonConvert?

Comment: From nuget ... just find JSON.Net and install

Comment: @user2941906 : Thanks. I have installed Json.net successfully. But now response has been changed. In the autos window it is 

 '"[{\"response\":\"true\",\"user_id\":\"350\",\"username\":\"BDO123456\"}]"'

Comment: Due to this change I am getting exception

Comment: @MohitGupta what kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: @kmatyaszek : JsonSerialiazationException was unhandeled. Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'app.UserData' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: @kmatyaszek : As far as I can understand this is due to backslashes. But when I print same response it is shown in proper format but when I try to deserialize it contain backslashes.

Comment: @MohitGupta I have updated `RootObject` (image json data from you question) and you should deserialize list of `RootObject` objects.

Comment: @kmatyaszek : I am using the same

Comment: @MohitGupta check deserialize line `var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseData);`

Comment: @kmatyaszek : I am sorry, I forgot to check last Line. Now after using this code exception has been removed but variables are containing null. When I tried to access this data using below code I got null.
'UserData ds = new UserData();
                    string res = ds.response;'

I used UserData instead of RootObject.

Comment: @MohitGupta  why you create a new object of `UserData`? If you create new object all properties of this object will be have default values so property response is equal to null in this case.

Comment: @kmatyaszek : to access values of variables of class UserData. Kindly guide me how can I access value of variables of UserData class.

Comment: @MohitGupta line of code `var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseData);` return  list of `RootObject`, you can use foreach loop to iterate over items and get properties value from each instance of object.

Comment: @kmatyaszek : I still have a question. How will I access values of UserData Class in other classes? Value of variables of UserData class will always be null.

Comment: @MohitGupta you should pass instance of your class (or instance of List<T>) to another class by constructor or method.

Comment: @kmatyaszek : yes I did the same but it always return null. I just created an instance of my class 

'UserData ds = new UserData();
string df = ds.current_balance;'

Value of df always null.

Comment: @MohitGupta I think that you should create new question and you must add more code which show your problem.

Comment: @kmatyaszek : Kindly guide me. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194872/accessing-public-class-from-another-class-in-wpf