# Accessing public class from another class in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a wpf application. In this application I received JSON response from server and deserialize it as follow :-

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(jsonResponse.GetResponseStream());
                String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseData);
                //UserData ud = new UserData();
                foreach (var val in myData)
                {
                    string res = val.response;
                    if (res == "true")
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        new lobby().Show();

                    }
                }
```

My class is as follow :-

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string current_balance { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string oauth_token { get; set; }
    public List<string> lastFiveSpinNumbers { get; set; }

}
```

When I execute this code everything is ok and after checking response `lobby.xaml` open. Now I need to access values of `RootObject` class in `lobby.xaml.cs`. So I created an instance of this class as follow:-

```
RootObject cd = new RootObject();
UserNameTextBlock.Text = cd.response;
```

but `cd.response` is always null. What may be the reason?

Comment: It will be null since you are creating an instance. just pass the object in the constructor and assign the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `RootObject` and by default the `response` property is `null`.

You can give your `lobby` class a constructor that takes in a `RootObject`:

```
public class lobby 
{
   public lobby(RootObject rootObject) 
   {
       UserNameTextBlock.Text = rootObject.response;
   }
}
```

Then in your `foreach` you could do:

```
if (res == "true")
{
   this.Hide();
   new lobby(val).Show(); // Pass the root object to the Lobby constructor
}
```

Note: You may wish to rename `lobby` to `Lobby` for your class name, this adheres to better `C#` naming conventions.